# circle problems

Tags: circles

I have no idea how to even start this question.

[image]

Could you please explain your reasoning. Also, the answer is approximately 57.3 degrees.

Comment: The answer is $\pi$. The large circle does 60 degrees and the and the small to the left 3 times that rotation.

Comment: Imagine removing a point from each circle so that it's just a curved line segment. Now think about laying that out flat. The circumference of the circle is the length of that line. Now it's like measuring out how many of the small segment fit into the larger one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with computing the angle that the spool must rotate to raise the weight 10cm:

$\theta_{S} r_{S} = 10 \text{ cm}$

$\theta_{S} = \frac{10}{30} \text { radians}$

Since Gear B is connected to the spool, the angle is the same.  However, the linear distance that the circumference translates through (at the point of contact with Gear A), is given by the expression:

$d=\theta_{S} r_{B} = \frac{10}{30} (90)$

Lastly, we determing the angle that Gear A rotates through from:

$d=\theta_{A} r_{A} =  \frac{10}{30} (90)$

since Gear A and Gear B are in contact, the distance d is in common.  Now we can solve for the angle $\theta_{A}$:

$\theta_{A} =  \frac{10}{30} \frac{90}{30} = \frac{1}{3} (3) = 1 \text{ radian}  $

$1 \text{ radian} = \frac{360}{2\pi} \text{ degrees} \approx 57.3 \text{ degrees} $

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you!
Can you solve this question by working with degrees instead of radians? Because radians, for me, are quite confusing :/

Comment: Where did the 90 come from in the 8th line --> d = ArA?